# Kubuntu 14.04 install crashes when reaching GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, kubuntu, system-installation, crash

I've been trying to install Kubuntu 14.04 on my desktop PC alongside my Windows 7 (I want to make a dual boot system), but the istallation always crashes at the point when the installer tries to set up GRUB at the end. I have 4 hard drives, two identical drives with 750mb capacity used in RAID 0, one 2TB drive, and a 500MB drive, which contains my Windows 7 installation. The latter is partitioned to hold a 300MN NTFS partition for the Win7, and I created a 170mb ext4 partition with "\" as mount point, and the rest (some 7gb or so) as a swap partition. The Kubuntu would go on the ext4, but as mentioned above, it crashes at the end of the install. However, when I try to boot my PC, I get a GRUB> prompt, so the win7 loader is replaced (I can repair it, that's no issue).
At the beginning of the installation the installer asks me if I wanted to download updates during the installation, and 3rd party stuff, but I didn't check in these, because when I do check them in, the installer hangs at the point of configuring some kind of broadcom driver (I have a wireless PCI card in the PC, I guess that causes tis other problem).
Hope I was detailed enough, does anyone have a suggestion for solving this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from your install media, using the try Ubuntu option.  Once Ubuntu is running, install "boot-repair".  It is a small GUI interface, run from the command line with "boot-repair" command.

The utility program has options for EFI or Boot.  It should repair your Win7 bootloader.  Also, once you manage to get Ubuntu up and running.  You may want to run the boot-repair utility before re-booting to make sure Grub has been re-installed correctly for the new install.  This was the only way I could get my dual boot issues resolved.

To install boot-repair, you must be booted into Ubuntu, grab the terminal emulator of choice:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-  trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

Once the install is finished the last command line launches the program.  Just follow the prompts and you should be OK.

Hope this will solve your issue.